# How to pass 2 arguments to dict() built-in function?

Tags: python, enumerate

How to pass 2 arguments to `dict()` built-in function? I want to put a function with one line of code using `enumerate()` function:

Given function:

```
def d_list(L):
    return dict(enumerate(L))

# call the function

print(d_list(['a','b','c']))
```

and the output was:

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

and I want the output as:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Please, I want a fast answer!

Comment: You could just reverse it manually...

Comment: ** so reversing it manually means that ``` return {value : key for (key , value) in enumerate(L):

Comment: Yep, Green Cloak Guy's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do the dict comprehension yourself.

```
def d_list(L):
    return {val: idx for (idx, val) in enumerate(L)}
```